# How is Unreal's 2D Blendspace implemented?

Tags: animation, parametrization

I'm currently trying to implement animation blending. Or more specifically, parametric animation. Unreal Engine has this in the form of [blendspaces](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/AnimatingObjects/SkeletalMeshAnimation/Blendspaces/Overview/). After some experimentation, I've noticed that they perform timewarping on the input animations *and then* blend. Meaning they change the way animations are sampled through time before performing any blending.

[image: An example of time warping between a running/jogging animation]

I'm having difficulty implementing timewarping and blending with more than just two animations, specifically the case for a 2D blendspace. Are there any recent papers/publications related to this? The most useful one I could find was [this one](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/graphics/Gallery/kovar.vol/RegistrationCurves/regCurves.pdf) from 2003. It seems more designed for static cases where the transitioning is preplanned, dynamic not as much.

Comment: What exactly causes you problems? We usually do not answer questions that are just asking for literature ([see here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) but if you can specify your problem, we might be able to help.

Comment: To be fair, I was only asking how it was implemented. I searched for a very long time but couldn't find anything on the internet, so I decided to ask for a baseline to keep it broad and simple.

I only posted the paper because I saw someone link the exact paper in [another stack exchange post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22402/animation-blending-basics).

Regardless, to anyone curious I found out the solution and it does involve timewarping but based on the number of frames in an animation in a barycentric + bilinear manner.